# Should I avoid operations between constants in a loop?

Tags: c++, performance, caching, optimization, constants

I would like to know if in c++ there is some kind of optimization or caching that prevents the same mathematical operation between constants from being repeated, especially in loops, thus decreasing application performance.
For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i ++)
    std::cout << i << "meters / s:" << "=" << i * (3600/1000) << "Km / h" << endl;
```

The above example is obviously fictional, but it is only to illustrate the situation. It could be a million-fold loop with hundreds of calculations involving repeated constants.

Then I ask:

1. Will the "(3600/1000)" calculation run repeatedly over the 100 times of the loop?
2. In this way, to avoid loss of performance should I store this calculation in a constant variable before the loop and change the calculation by that variable?
3. Or do not I have to worry about it because c++ gives a way to optimize these situations automatically to avoid performance loss?
4. Or even if I change 3600 for constant "a" and 1000 for constant "b", that is, instead of 3600/1000 I have "a / b", even though "a" and "b" are constant, yet the operation is calculated 100 times repeatedly or is there any optimization?

I understand that this question is pertinent, since it involves the programming style that should be adopted.

Comment: It depends on your compiler.  Most modern compilers will optimize it to a constant.

Comment: You don't really need to worry. Compiler is smart enough to replace `3600/1000` with `360` at compile time.

Comment: C++ explicitly allows the compiler to implement any optimization that has no observable effects. Performing the optimization you outlined has no observable effects, so this will be allowed. The C++ standard does not require the compiler to implement this optimization, only allows it; but in practice all modern C++ compilers will do this, especially when it involves only constants.

Comment: almost all compilers will optimise away literal computations. BTW with a small loop like yours (0 to 100) you are worrying about unnecessary optimisation

Comment: The constant will be calculated once at compile time. Don't worry about micro-optimization. Speed these days is mostly about avoiding cache misses and blocking on I/O. If it did the division every time through the loop (which it won't, but if), you probably could not measure the difference in a real program. Think of calculation a "free".

Comment: I guess you meant 3.6 but.. it seems to me like it will result in 3 instead? 3600 of int / 1000 of int looks like 3. If you are not using a very funny so-called research compiler for a freshly-born processor, any of you mentioned should result in compile time constant calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reads like a comment but is quite relevant as an answer to your worry.

*The compiler is smarter than you.*

This is a very good rule of thumb when trying to write fast code.

Write code that is readable, your compiler will most likely do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the snippet you've shown. Constant folding is a basic optimization technique. So is loop unrolling (especially with fixed number of iterations).

The only thing you need is a compiler flag to activate optimizations: -O3 (or others) on clang/GCC, /O3 for MSVC.

Even though, the code will be working perfectly, I would suggest to give your magic constants a name to improve readability:

```
constexpr static const auto SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 3600;
constexpr static const auto METERS_IN_KILOMETER = 1000;
constexpr static const auto FACTOR_KILOMETER_PER_HOUR_TO_METERS_PER_SECOND = static_cast<double>(SECONDS_IN_HOUR) / static_cast<double>(METERS_IN_KILOMETER);
```

As this are constexpr, these should be calculated at compile time and by result can't cause runtime overhead. This will even work without optimizations enabled.

Note that from C++17, these constants are implicitly inline. So you might need some changes in case you use an old compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Some cpu's will keep repeated calculations in their own cache.

My recommendation would be to have the result in there so it never has to do that. Also always use braces, just in case you have more complex structures added on later.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i ++) {
    std::cout << i << "meters / s:" << "=" << i * 3.6 << "Km / h" << endl;
}
```

For other, more complex objects, maybe only run calculations where the result is required straight away, or pre-calculate and store results for use later.

Comment: -O1 will most likely optimize this already. Don't suggest micro optimizations. If one wants to write `3600./1000.` because these 2 numbers have meaning, just write them.